# cakephp view not echo'ing

Tags: php, cakephp, if-statement, view

i have a page that has an if statement with an echo in it and the echo is not printing to the screen even though the conditions are being met. When debugging $invoicedetails **scheduled** is equal to **true**

here is the relevant information from my view

```
<?php

    if($invoicedetails['Invoice']['scheduled']==1)
    {
        $status = 'Scheduled';  
        $fcol = 'Black';
        $bgcol = '#EBD8E8';
        $pay = NULL;
        $dispute = NULL;
    }
    else if($invoicedetails['Invoice']['paid']==1)
    {
        $status = 'Paid';
        $fcol = 'Black';
        $bgcol = '#B9FAEA';
        $pay = NULL;
        $dispute = NULL;
    }
    else if($invoicedetails['Invoice']['sender_id']==$accountid)
    {
        $status = 'Sent';
        $fcol = 'Black';
        $bgcol = '#F8FAC0';
        $pay = NULL;
        $dispute = NULL;
    }
    else if($invoicedetails['Invoice']['receiver_id']==$accountid)
    {
        $status = 'Received';
        $fcol = 'Black';
        $bgcol = '#FAB9B9';


        $pay = $this->Html->link('Pay', array('controller' => 'Invoices','action'=>'pay_admin',$invoicedetails['Invoice']['id'] )) ;
        $dispute = $this->Html->link('Dispute', array('controller' => 'Disputes','action'=>'add_admin',$invoicedetails['Invoice']['id'] ));

    }



?>  


    <tr>
            <th>Actions: </th>
            <td>
            <?php 
            if($invoicedetails['Invoice']['scheduled']=='true'){ 
                echo $pay; 
            }
            ?> 
            <?php echo  $dispute; ?></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: if $invoicedetails['Invoice']['scheduled']= true then it always go into first if and there you made $pay=NULL ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're having way too much logic in your View. That kind of stuff goes in your Controller. The reason why it's not showing anything, is because you tell it not to.

First you do:

```
if($invoicedetails['Invoice']['scheduled']==1) {
    // (...)
    $pay = NULL;
    $dispute = NULL;
}
```

And then you tell it to echo those NULL values:

```
if($invoicedetails['Invoice']['scheduled']=='true') { 
    echo $pay; 
}
echo  $dispute;
```

So yes, it is echo'ing thos null values. What were you expecting to see?

Additionally, in the first check you're matching against the integer 1. In the second one, you're matching against the string (so not boolean) true. Which one is it? If it's a 0/1 field, drop the quotes around `true`, so you get:

```
if($invoicedetails['Invoice']['scheduled'] == true) {
```

Or (even shorter) just drop the entire true bit:

```
if($invoicedetails['Invoice']['scheduled']) {
```

Comment: Controller? Definitely no. http://www.mikebernat.com/images/cake/layercake.png This should be a helper.

Comment: @burzum Helpers are more of a "global" extension to views that you can use more than once. Doesn't look very likely in this case, those are just `$this->set` controller bits based on specific conditions. As the book says: "Helpers are the component-like classes for the presentation layer of your application. They contain presentational logic that is **shared between many views, elements, or layouts**."